# Syntax for series with parameter

Tags: syntax, series-expansion

I am totally new to this - I cannot find how I can find a series limit that has also parameters, ie like

$  a_n  =   \sqrt{(kn+2)} + \sqrt{(n)}  , ~~k \in (0,+\infty )$

edit : cross-posted here https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2211904 (by me)

Comment: Did you try plotting the series for different parameter values? Check whether or not it is diverging or converging around a point?

Comment: that is my problem, I do not know how to even input that ...furthermore, I would be interested to see the solution of it, not just Plot[]

Comment: [The documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) to `Series` includes an example `Series[AiryAi[a x], {x, Infinity, 0}, Assumptions -> (a > 0)]` in its Option/Assumptions section.

Comment: That's a sequence not a series.

Comment: Please add links to/from Wolfram Community x-post.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered on the Wolfram Community site.

Answer (score 0):

Series is possible a wrong choice for the problem You hat in mind because it is a Mathematica built-in with the task to develop function into approximation around or at certain value.

What You hat in mind is `Table` or `Array`. In a graphic:

```
ListPlot[Table[Sqrt[k n + 2] + Sqrt[n], {k, 1, 5}, {n, 1, 25}]]
```

[image]

The answer is then:

```
Limit[Sqrt[k n + 2] + Sqrt[n], n -> \[Infinity]$]
```

(* DirectedInfinity[1 + Sqrt[k]] *)

The computable values for $a_{n}$ tend to positive infinity faster an usual $n$ by an factor of $1+\sqrt k$. Limit is the border if it exists for the values of $n$ not of $k$.

```
Limit[Limit[Sqrt[k n + 2] + Sqrt[n], n -> \[Infinity]], 
 k -> \[Infinity]]
```

$\infty$

This interprets the $a_{k,n}$ as a double definition of functional values.

Existing for example does:

```
Limit[Sqrt[ n + 2/k] - Sqrt[n], n -> \[Infinity]]
```

$0$.

You come intom Mathematica with the keyword "series limit". "series" is something else different from Your intent both in Mathematica and mathematics. "limit" is `Limit` in Mathematica and matches most probable Your intent complete. This is general experience most starters make in mathematics and Mathematica. Nothing is wrong with this. Clearance is needed for list in Mathematica.

Mathematica has some predesessors in the kategory of programming languages. One of them is Lisp. The is an acronym for list processing language. So almost everthing in mathematica is a list. Accompanying this is the concept of rules. So `Series` is a built-in working with rather different objects from mathematics than implied by the usage of series in Your problem.

On the behalf of the textbook or course You attend and got the problem from the terminus series is not unique. It is used for the object of the problem and apprimation to functions for example a Taylor series. There is a duality between the coefficient list and the series representation but the terminus series remains for the approximation to a function around or at a point. Why do they intermingle the two terms is not clear at all. Most probable this come from the German language in which it in possible to mix list with series.